# C++ single step in debugger throws an exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a C++ app that will throw an exception when I try to single step from a breakpoint. For example:

1) Start app from VS2010 0 debugger is attached.

2) Set a breakpoint. It doesn't seem to matter where.

3) Do something in the app so that it hits the break point.

** VS2010 hits the break point

4) Single step the debugger to the next line of code.

VS2010 pops up a message box with this exception:

"Unhandled exception at 0x087df66f in SimpleGraphSDI.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation."

Note that if I set a breakpoint on two consecutive lines of code, and press run to advance from one line to another, the app "runs" to the next line of code with no issues. The access violation is only when I use the single step command from VS2010.

Some code in the app has been around since VC6 and maybe earlier. However do not know if this is relevant.

**UPDATE:** The exception when single stepping the debugger does **not** occur if I start the app, and then attach the debugger after the app has started.

Comment: Are you using that GFX lib to take exclusive control of the screen? I.e. switching your app to fullscreen?

Comment: Please post the smallest code that duplicates the issue.

Comment: There really isn't enough information here to help you.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but here are things to try:
Restart Visual Studio; 
Do a clean build of your application; 
Display the disassembly window and step through instructions to see what is going on.

Is this a multi-thread application?  Is it possible other threads are at work?  What does the stack trace tell you when you hit the access violation?

Comment: Try breaking on the access violation and looking at a stack trace. Find out which module owns `0x087df66f` and how execution ended up there.

Comment: Depending upon where I set the break point, the address of the access violation varies. Strangely, the last four bytes are always the same. for example: 0x099BF6F6, 0x0724F6F6, 0x08CBF6F6. Weird.

Comment: I'm using the "base address" reported by process explorer to try to locate what module owns that address. It appears to be a different module each time. Unless that's not the correct way to determine the module.

Answer (score 2):

A work around for this problem is to disable RPC debugging.

In the Visual Studio 2010, Visual Studio 2010 SP1 toolbar select below steps -

Tools->Options->Debugging->Native and deselect "Enable RPC debugging"

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same issue.  I was able to solve it by starting VS from the command line telling it to reset the UI to default `(/ResetSettings)` Details on the command line arguments are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx)

I did not need to reboot after resetting VS, but I did a full rebuild of the project after completing the reset of the environment.

Comment: This worked for me as well for a similar issue - for me, I did not need to step manually through the debugger.  Just running in debug mode was sufficient.  (The erroneous access violation always occurred during a JNI call in my case.)  /ResetSettings (followed immediately by a rebuild) resolved the issue immediately.  Incidentally, for any who may not know, it's "devenv.exe" in the appropriate folder that is the EXE to run at the command line with /ResetSettings.

Answer (score 0):

There maybe exist a thread that somehow detects that the code is being debugged step by step and pagefaults in response to prevent you from debugging. Try to locate that thread by suspending threads one by one.

Also, is address 0x087df66f always the same? If it is then you can set a breakpoint there and look around when the breakpoint is hit.