# Access violation calling a native (C++) function from Java using JNI: Is this an issue with my code, or a known issue?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have a native function, defined in my C++ code, that is called within Java (after the Java code is called by C++).

(1) Declaration / definition of the native function in C++:

```
// C++ declaration/definition of the native function:

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL setEncoderProgressStatus (JNIEnv * env, jobject theClass, jlong jEncoderDecoderDlg, jstring status)
{
    // Do nothing.  Obviously, the real function does something.
    // But an access violation is reported even in the do-nothing case.
}
```

(2) Registration of the native function in C++

```
// Registration of this function with JNI in the C++ code

JNINativeMethod commandLineEncoderMethods[] =
{
    {"setEncoderProgressStatus","(JLjava/lang/String;)V", (void*)setEncoderProgressStatus}
};

// pEnv is a valid JNIEnv *
// jCommandLineEncoderClass has already been initialized
pEnv->RegisterNatives(jCommandLineEncoderClass, commandLineEncoderMethods, sizeof(commandLineEncoderMethods)/sizeof(JNINativeMethod))
```

(3) Declaration of the native function in Java:

```
// The Java code, in turn, declares the native function as follows:

public static native void setEncoderProgressStatus(long EncoderDecoderDlg, String status);
```

(4) Calling the native function within the Java code:

```
// Finally, the Java code calls the native function as follows:

// The real code passes different args,
// but an access violation is reported even in the do-nothing case.
// Commenting out the following line of code makes the access violation disappear.

setEncoderProgressStatus(0, "");
```

Note that this code works 100% successfully, and has worked for a long time.  I just noticed that when running in the debugger in Visual Studio 2010, an access violation is reported.  Simply commenting out the call to the native function in Java, causes the access violation to disappear.

If I knew that this is a known "fluke" with JNI when running applications in debug mode in VS 2010, and that it does not represent a problem with my code, then I would be satisfied.

However, I would like to confirm that there is no possible problem with my code.

...

*** ADDENDUM ***

The access violations do not cause program execution to halt.  Instead, the only indication of the access violation is a line in the Output window.  I am not sure if this means that the access violation was handled or not; however, I would guess it means that it was handled.  Even if it's handled, however, I would like to know if it necessarily indicates that there is a problem with my code.

Here is the message in the Output window:

> First-chance exception at 0x03fbb256 in EncoderDecoder.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x003d0100

...

*** SECOND ADDENDUM ***

I find that when the C++ application remains connected to the JVM, and I execute the same code again from the C++ application (causing the same Java code to be called, which in turn causes the Java code to call the same JNI function), that the access violations *do not* appear.

(In my actual program, there are a number of different native functions called within a number of different classes, so it's not simple to isolate exactly when the access violation is reported, and when it stops being reported - but by the third run of the same functionality without quitting the C++ application, using the same loaded JVM, there are **no** first-chance access violation errors (and no plain access violation errors, either)).

This leads me to believe, in conjunction with Ben Voigt's answer (and associated comments) below, that the JVM code *does* cause a `first-chance exception (access violation)` to occur as part of its NORMAL processing, and that this is not an issue with my code.

...

*** ADDENDUM 3 ***

From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx:

> First chance exception messages most often do not mean there is a
>   problem in the code.

There still is the possibility that a first-chance exception that happens to be an *access violation* is more likely to represent a real problem, in which case my question is still open; but - I think the evidence points to the possibility that this is just how the JVM works, and does not represent a problem with my code.

Comment: Applying telepathic powers... ESP circuit overrdrive... Running hot... Nah, zilch! Sorry.

Comment: I guess I'm specifically wondering if this is a known issue.  Obviously there could be problems with my code, but if it's already a known issue (there are other known issues with the VS 2010 debugger reporting false access violations; e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11113179/368896), then why spend the time hunting down ghosts?

Comment: It's unlikely to be a false report.  Access violations can and sometimes do occur as part of normal program control flow.  Have you tried with any other debugger (i.e. WinDbg)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it an unhandled access violation, or does the call proceed if you continue (letting the exception handler run)?

JIT compilers have a whole bunch of tricks to generate the native code for a function without every call suffering the cost of a conditional to see if the function has been JITted.  One such technique is for the first call to be intercepted because it generates an access violation to trigger the JIT compiler.  After the code has been generated once, future calls go through without an exception.

I'm not familiar with whether any Java JIT compiler actually does so, but you can't get a definitive answer without giving specific information about what JIT you're running.  Is it the Sun/Oracle HotSpot compiler?  x86 or x86_64 or some other platform?  You're deep into implementation details which vary by implementation.

Comment: The code does not even stop in the debugger.  It runs without error, even in debug mode.  The only indication of the access violation is a line in the Output window.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: Very likely you have your debugger configured to stop on unhandled access violation, not first chance.  It's the "Exceptions" dialog (accessed from the Debug menu IIRC) that controls this.

Comment: And "1.7" is not nearly specific enough version information.  Besides that, it's the runtime environment, not the `javac` version, that counts.

Comment: The JDK is, more specifically: jdk1.7.0_09 (x86).

Comment: Are you using the JDK or JRE runtime?

Comment: Also, the debugger is actually not stopping on the access violation.  The program runs fine.  Instead, the only indication is a line in the VS Output window.  If I am to understand that access violations (that are handled, if I'm correct that mine is being handled because program execution does not stop) are possible as part of **normal** program execution, then I'm satisfied it's likely not a problem with my code.

Comment: I am compiling the Java application with the JDK I mentioned above - jdk1.7.0_09 (x86).  When the C++ application runs and loads the JVM, it loads it from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\client\".

Comment: Not every access violation indicates a bug.  If you want to see what happens when the access violation occurs, set the Visual Studio debugger to break on first-chance exception.  Then you can step through the handler.  I expect you'd be dumped into JRE code that triggers loading the native DLL and JITs any trampoline needed.

Comment: If you happen to have it handy, do you know of an easy example of an access violation that does not indicate a bug?  This would be enlightening.  (Granted, it's not my question.)

Comment: Indeed, when I set VS to break on exceptions, it breaks deep in the midst of JVM functions - not particularly helpful.

Comment: For example, the whole virtual memory system is built on access violations (at least the part dealing with swapping memory out to disk).  Those page faults are handled by the OS though, and never seen by your program.  Copy-on-write is another example of an access violation used for control flow.  And the Win64 kernel anti-patching system uses access violations in at least some versions.  I'll find you the link.

Comment: Stack growth also uses an access violation: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100775